# How to display model's primary key in django during update

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

In some of my models I have used the primary key defined by the system (Django) whereas in some others I have defined my own primary keys.

In the second instance (i.e. for models with custom primary keys), while updating / changing a record, I am able to show the primary key (as a readonly field) in the page being presented to the user (through a template). This is what I am unable to replicate for models with system defined primary key.

Comment: You can just reference the id in the template

Comment: Also include the relevant code for the second example where you want to display the primary key field.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the primary key of a model instance, just use `{{ your_model_instance.pk }}` in your template.

Comment: Thanks . In my template I am looping through the form fields to display them. Where I need to, I capture the field name like `{% if field.name == "<field_name>" %}` `{{ field }}` `{% endif %}`. But somehow my code `{% if field.name == "id" %}` is NOT WORKING. If I use `{{ <table_name>.id }}` OR `{{ <table_name>.pk }}` OR even `{{ form.instance.id }}` without a conditional statement, I am able to display the model's "`id`". If I may ask, is there a way to capture the `<field_name>` for **id** so that I may use the existing `for..loop` without additional formatting of table field (using css).

Comment: If your field is called `id` (which is not a good name for a field btw), you can try `{% if field.id_for_label == id_id %}` (or just print `{{ field.id_for_label }}` to see what you should set if it not `id_id`.

Comment: Like I have already _mentioned_, the key field is system generated [source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields).